# PropTypes for an unknown default value

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a higher order component for fields in a form that checks for a default value on mount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let existingValue = this.props.getValue(this.props.name)
  if (existingValue) {
    this.setState({ value: existingValue })
  } else {
    this.props.update(this.props.name, '')
  }
}
```

with `this.props.update` setting a default value in the form component parent. This works well with any text-type field or selects, but it does not work with checkboxes.

In my specific field types I am using PropTypes to check the value type:

```
Text.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

But in my checkbox component I'd like to avoid doing this:

```
Checkbox.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.oneOf(['', bool]),
}
```

I don't believe I can use `defaultProps` for this because I am using a HoC for the field and a component for each field type. Is there a way I can keep my structure without doing complex checking for value AND value type?

Comment: Any reason as to why you don't want to use `oneOf` as you described?

Comment: I guess I'd be concerned about losing the value of PropTypes altogether - for my Text component the value MUST be an empty string or a string, anything else will prompt a warning. I was hoping to achieve the same level of certainty for my boolean fields.